# Badge count is not increment/decrement in iOS App

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

We are migrating from Urban Airship to Salesforce MobilePush.

I am using `react-native-marketingcloudsdk`, when I am sending push notification, the AppIcon Badge counts are not getting increment, also when I tap the notification it's not getting decrement. Please help me on this, we have to go live by this week.

It's keeps showing `1` as badge, even when I uninstall and re-install it's remain same.

Also in Salesforce Cloud > Mobile Push, it's not showing opened status for iOS.

Please find below ticket for my `AppDelegate.m` and `AppDelegate.h`
[sfmc_handleURL is not working for iOS with react-native-marketingcloudsdk](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/390878/sfmc-handleurl-is-not-working-for-ios-with-react-native-marketingcloudsdk)

**We have enabled Badging in MobilePush**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have inbox enabled to have the badge count incremented and badge count is increased for inbox , Alert +inbox messages only.

Consuming application can override the badging set by SDK as well.

Below document explains on badging:

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/use-cases/use-cases.html

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/application-badging/application-badging.html

Thanks
Prakashini